# How to calculate standard deviation and average values of RDD[Long]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `RDD[Long]` called `mod` and I want to compute standard deviation and mean values for this RDD using Spark 2.2 and Scala 2.11.8.

How can I do it?

I tried to calculate the average value as follows, but is there any easier way to get these values?

```
val avg_val = mod.toDF("col").agg(
    avg($"col").as("avg")
).first().toString().toDouble

val stddev_val = mod.toDF("col").agg(
    stddev($"col").as("avg")
).first().toString().toDouble
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have RDD[Long] called mod and I want to compute standard deviation and mean

Just use `stats`:

```
scala> val mod = sc.parallelize(Seq(1L, 3L, 5L))
mod: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Long] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val stats = mod.stats
stats: org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter = (count: 3, mean: 3.000000, stdev: 1.632993, max: 5.000000, min: 1.000000)

scala> stats.mean
res0: Double = 3.0

scala> stats.stdev
res1: Double = 1.632993161855452
```

It uses the same internals a `stdev` and `mean` but has to scan data only once.

With `Dataset` I'd recommend:

```
val (avg_val, stddev_val) = mod.toDS
  .agg(mean("value"), stddev("value"))
  .as[(Double, Double)].first
```

or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val Row(avg_val: Double, stddev_val: Double) = mod.toDS
  .agg(mean("value"), stddev("value"))
  .first
```

but it neither necessary nor useful here.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is pretty simple:

```
mod.stdev()
mod.mean()
```