# how to normalize multiple columns of a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Data frame with columns as `Col_A , Col_B , label` .

`Col_A` and `Col_B` is of type Double, and label is of Integer type.

How can i normalise or standardise Col_A and Col_B(not "label" column) (without converting into vector) such that the new data frame have separate Columns as Col_A_norm , Col_B_norm and label 
where

value of a row of `Col_A_norm = (value of a row of Col_A - mean of Col_A)/standard deviation of Col_A`

and

value of a row of `Col_B_norm = (value of a row of Col_B - mean of Col_B)/standard deviation of Col_B`

Comment: [Feature normalization algorithm in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34234817/8371915)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48139129/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation-and-average-values-of-rddlong

Comment: But by that method , ultimately all the columns will be converted into a vector containing normalized values , but i want separate normalized columns in the newly formed dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

Try this exmaple

```
val dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, 1.0, 0.5),
  (1, 2.0, 1.0),
  (2, 4.0, 10.0)
)).toDF("label", "Col_A", "Col_B")

val stat = dataFrame.describe("Col_A", "Col_B")
  .select(col("summary"), col("Col_A").cast("double"), col("Col_B").cast("double"))
  .collect.map(_.toSeq.toArray).transpose.map(x => x.slice(1,3))

dataFrame.select(col("label"), col("Col_A").minus(stat(1)(0)).divide(stat(1)(1)).as("Col_A"),
   col("Col_B").minus(stat(2)(0)).divide(stat(2)(1)).as("Col_B")).show
```